# I would like to print the arithmetic sequence triangle

Tags: algorithm, math, sequence

I would like to print the 'number' triangle like the below sequence.

1 2 4 7 11

3 5 8 12

6 9 13

10 14

15

assume that give n is 5.

means that column will give 5 and column - 1.
also, the row is 5.

I found that every each column increase 1 - 2 - 3 -4
and row increase 2, 3, 4, 5.

How would I able to get this triangle?

I tried like below however, I can not find the way since row 2.

```
int n;
scanf("%d", &n);
int sum = 0;
int x = 0;
for(int j = 0; j <= 2; j = j + 2)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    if(i < 2)
    {
      x = 1;
    }

    sum = sum + x+j;
    x++;
    printf("%d ", sum);
  }
  sum = 0;
  printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add 2 `FOR` loop, the outer loop can be for each row and the inner loop can be for each column value.

See below code :

```
int number, currentValue, nextRowValue, nextColValue;

nextRowValue = 1;
nextColValue = 1;

printf("Number? : ");
scanf("%d", &number);
for(int rowIndex=0; rowIndex < number; rowIndex++)
{
    nextColValue = nextRowValue;

    for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < number - rowIndex; colIndex++)
    {
        currentValue = colIndex + nextColValue +rowIndex;

        printf("%d \t", currentValue);

        nextColValue = currentValue;
    }

    printf("\n");

    nextRowValue = (nextRowValue + (rowIndex + 1));
}
printf("\n");
```

Try this code, if it works for you. Also, try to understand the code or let me know if you are having any doubts.

Answer (score 0):

Small modification makes the code to work properly

```
int n;
scanf_s("%d", &n);
for (int line = 0; line < n; line++)
{
    int sum = (line + 1) * (line + 2) / 2;
    for (int col = 0; col < n - line; col++)
    {
        sum = sum + col;
        printf("%d ", sum);
        sum = sum + line;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

6
1 2 4 7 11 16
3 5 8 12 17
6 9 13 18
10 14 19
15 20
21
```

As variant:

```
int base = 1;
for (int line = 0; line < n; line++)
{
    int sum = base + line;
    for (int col = 0; col < n - line; col++)
    {
        sum = sum + col;
        printf("%d ", sum);
        sum = sum + line;
    }
    base = base + line + 1;
    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here two proposals:

**Proposal 1: using an array to store the first line**

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 5

int main(void) {
    int line1[N];
    int i, j;

    line1[0]=1;
    for(i=1;i<N;i++) {
        line1[i]= line1[i-1]+i;
    }

    for(i=0;i<N;i++) {
        for(j=0;j<N-i;j++) {
            printf("%d ", line1[i+j]+i);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return(0);
}
```

**Proposal 2: without storing intermediate results**

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 5

int main(void) {
    int i, j;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++) {
        for(j=0;j<N-i;j++) {
            printf("%d ", (j+i+1)*(j+i+0)/2+1+i);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return(0);
}
```